# How to create a list of nodes that the anonymous user has created and limit it by the current session (SID)?

Tags: nodes, users, sessions

Is there a way to create a list of nodes that the anonymous user has created and limit it only by the user's current session?

Basically I want the anonymous user to create a node under a specific content type and give that user a list of nodes (maybe using views) that he or she created only during the his or her current session on the site.

Anybody willing to help? I've been trying this the whole day and can't seem to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) to grab the nid of the node that is being created. Take the nid and add it to $_SESSION. Then create a View that accepts NIDs as contextual arguments. You'll need to do some additional coding to grab those NIDs from the session and pass it to the View.

Comment: but how does it prevent access from others?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry but I'm not that code savvy, I'm not used to using hooks and the sort. Is there a way to make this easier?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to limit views based on the user's current session?

Comment: @AyeshK... what are you trying to prevent access to?  This solution simply stores the list of nodes an anonymous user created so we can easily display that list of nodes.

Comment: @JoshuaAbellare... I'm not aware of any existing modules that do what you're looking for. This would require a small amount of coding to accomplish.